# How to write a WHERE to equate on two columns contains both NULL and empty values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, qsqlquery

[image: Table structure and values]

Given is my table structure, now I need to write a query to compare "STRVAL1 and STRVAL2" then "BVAL1 and BVAL2", if both are not same, then that row should be returned.

Expected result...

[image]

Please use the bellow script for data

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT, STRVAL1 VARCHAR(8), STRVAL2 VARCHAR(8), BVAL1 BIT, BVAL2 BIT)

    INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES 
      (1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    , (2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    , (3, '', '', NULL, NULL)
    , (4, 'VAL', 'VAL', NULL, NULL)
    , (5, 'VAL1', 'VAL2', NULL, NULL)
    , (6, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL)
    , (7, NULL, NULL, 0, 0)
    , (8, NULL, NULL, 1, 1)
    , (9, NULL, NULL, 1, 0)

    SELECT ID, STRVAL1, STRVAL2, BVAL1, BVAL2
    FROM @TAB
```

Comment: Something like using ISNULL(Field,'') <> ''

Comment: @Christopher  - is was thinking about ISNULL and COALESCE - but what if the non-null side contains your alternative value - if you COALESCE to 'N/A' it goes wrong if you comapre to 'N/A' - plus the other is a bit field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use comparisons, although `NULL`s make this a bit cumbersome:

```
select t.*
from @tab t
where ((strval1 <> strval2) or
       (strval1 is null and strval2 is not null) or
       (strval1 is not null and strval2 is null)
      ) or
      ((bval1 <> bval2) or
       (bval1 is null and bval2 is not null) or
       (bval1 is not null and bval2 is null)
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of tests.

```
select ... from ... where
(strval1 is null and strval2 is not null) or
(strval1 is not null and strval2 is null) or
(strval1 != strval2) or
(bval1 is null and bval2 is not null) or
(bval1 is not null and bval2 is null) or
(bval1 != bval2)
```